# Postgres single table query returns duplicates with large in clause

Tags: postgresql

I have a query as follows

```
select a.* from EVENTS a   
where  
a.id_type = 513 and 
a.id_type in (406,510,511,512,513) 
AND a.id_parent_type in(
    407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416
    ,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426
    ,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,436
    ,437,438,439,440,441,442,443,444,445,446
    ,447,448,449,450,451,452,453,454,455,456
)
order by created_on DESC, a.id ASC 
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
```

Primary key is **id**.
There is an index on **id_type**.
There is no index on **id_parent_type**.

When I run this query in a postgres 11.6 database, I get duplicate rows. Running the query repeatedly returns distinct rows sometimes, running it again returns duplicates.
*(both in psql, pgadmin, or from .net)*

In my mind it should not be possible for this query to return duplicates.

Things I have tried :

1. Removing the first `a.id_type = 513` clause will prevent the
   duplicates.
2. Dropping the index on `id_type` will prevent the
   duplicates, but does a full scan on a large table.

I know the `a.id_type = 513 and a.id_type in (406,510,511,512,513)`  are a bit redundant, but the query is dynamically built by a framework that allows for some user filtering.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

PS. I have a test environment clone of this database on the same server, restored using pg_restore where I can't duplicate the issue.

**UPDATE**
Fiddle here, cannot duplicate, but postgres version is different, I am on 11.6 on windows.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=453470fbb4e84f889b21a5f8f51e8cf8

**UPDATE2**
Explain Plan that does not work:

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Limit",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Actual Rows": 100,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Gather Merge",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Actual Rows": 100,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Workers Planned": 1,
          "Workers Launched": 1,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Sort",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Actual Rows": 65,
              "Actual Loops": 2,
              "Sort Key": [
                "sys_created_on DESC",
                "id"
              ],
              "Sort Method": "top-N heapsort",
              "Sort Space Used": 214,
              "Sort Space Type": "Memory",
              "Workers": [
                {
                  "Worker Number": 0,
                  "Sort Method": "top-N heapsort",
                  "Sort Space Used": 194,
                  "Sort Space Type": "Memory"
                }
              ],
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Index Scan",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Parallel Aware": true,
                  "Scan Direction": "Forward",
                  "Index Name": "idx_events_id_type",
                  "Relation Name": "events",
                  "Alias": "a",
                  "Actual Rows": 56763,
                  "Actual Loops": 2,
                  "Index Cond": "((id_type = ANY ('{406,510,511,512,513}'::integer[])) AND (id_type = 513))",
                  "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
                  "Filter": "(id_parent_type = ANY ('{407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,442,443,444,445,446,447,448,449,450,451,452,453,454,455,456}'::integer[]))",
                  "Rows Removed by Filter": 19666
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Triggers": []
  }
]
```

Explain Plan that works:

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Limit",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Actual Rows": 100,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Gather Merge",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Actual Rows": 100,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Workers Planned": 2,
          "Workers Launched": 2,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Sort",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Actual Rows": 33,
              "Actual Loops": 3,
              "Sort Key": [
                "sys_created_on DESC",
                "id"
              ],
              "Sort Method": "top-N heapsort",
              "Sort Space Used": 208,
              "Sort Space Type": "Memory",
              "Workers": [
                {
                  "Worker Number": 0,
                  "Sort Method": "quicksort",
                  "Sort Space Used": 25,
                  "Sort Space Type": "Memory"
                },
                {
                  "Worker Number": 1,
                  "Sort Method": "quicksort",
                  "Sort Space Used": 25,
                  "Sort Space Type": "Memory"
                }
              ],
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Bitmap Heap Scan",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Parallel Aware": true,
                  "Relation Name": "events",
                  "Alias": "a",
                  "Actual Rows": 37712,
                  "Actual Loops": 3,
                  "Recheck Cond": "((id_type = ANY ('{406,510,511,512,513}'::integer[])) AND (id_type = 513))",
                  "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
                  "Filter": "(id_parent_type = ANY ('{407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,442,443,444,445,446,447,448,449,450,451,452,453,454,455,456}'::integer[]))",
                  "Rows Removed by Filter": 12102,
                  "Exact Heap Blocks": 28716,
                  "Lossy Heap Blocks": 0,
                  "Plans": [
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                      "Parallel Aware": false,
                      "Index Name": "idx_events_id_type",
                      "Actual Rows": 150565,
                      "Actual Loops": 1,
                      "Index Cond": "((id_type = ANY ('{406,510,511,512,513}'::integer[])) AND (id_type = 513))"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Triggers": []
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13

Comment: I can't even reproduce it in a copy of the same database running on the same server.   The table has over 400k rows.

Comment: DOING `INNER JOIN ( VALUES (406), (510), (511), (512), (513)) vals(v) on a.id_type = v`  INSTEAD OF `a.id_type in (406,510,511,512,513)`  also causes no duplicates to be returned.   I think the two IN clauses are causing the issue but I can't prove it. Just because I don't get duplicates now, I can't guarantee that it wont happen

Comment: Added fiddle anyways, but seems to work.

Comment: "I am on 11.6 on windows"  You shouldn't run a version with known  bugs.

Comment: What is the execution plan for a case that shows the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately it is running on azure,(postgres as a service) I have no control on the version at the moment.

Comment: I have posted 2 explain plans. Looks like the one that does work does a "Bitmap Heap Scan", and the one that does not work does an "Index Scan",. Not sure what that means. Also "Workers Planned": 2, vs "Workers Planned": 1? Thanks

Comment: As a sanity check, could you verify that a count(*) of the query without limit is the same as count distinct?

Comment: select count(*), count(distinct id) from EVENTS
553287;553287